# How i can create database of a restaurant menu?

Tags: database

I want to create the database of a restaurant menu but i'm confused about the category and sub category. The customer will order the sub-category so then why we need to add main category in a table? How to design the database of a menu?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question and is a bit broad to answer as-is.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague. However, I expect you would have a category table and a sub category table as follows

**TblCategory**

```
CategoryID(int),
CategoryName(varchar)
```

**TblSubCategory**

```
SubCategoryID (int)
SubCategoryName(varchar)
CategoryID(int)
```

Alternatively, you could so this using one table which holds both categorys and subcategories.

**TblCategory**

```
CategoryID (int)
CategoryName(varchar)
ParentCategoryID(int)
```

The best solution and indeed the need for the main category depends on your requirements, which we don't know